# Ruby on Rails using existing database ID not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails app that uses an existing database. The existing database has a field of `id` which is an auto increment primary key in the DB but Ruby on Rails does not seem to use this as I get an error of `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

My edit.html.erb is:

```
<%= form_for (@activevulnerabilities) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">

        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Edit Vulnerability Type</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="box-body">
          <%= render partial: 'admin/active_vulnerabilities/form', locals: { f: f } %>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">
          <%= link_to 'Cancel', active_vulnerabilities_path, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller is:

```
class Admin::ActiveVulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  layout :layout_by_resource
  def index
    @activevulnerabilities = ActiveVulnerability.all
  end

  def edit
    @activevulnerability = ActiveVulnerability.find(params[:id])
  end

  private def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      'layouts/devise'
    else
      'admin/layouts/admin'
    end
  end
  private def set_active_vulnerability
    @activevulnerability = ActiveVulnerability.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edit action you are setting `@activevulnerability` variable and in view you are trying to access `@activevulnerabilities` variable which is `nil`. Fix variable naming and it should be okay.